# ActiveMQ Fail-over: How to set the maximum reconnect delay

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I'm using ActiveMQ (5.7) failover. I want to decrease the maximum time the application waits before deciding that a broker cannot be connected to, and moves onto the next. According to the [ActiveMQ fail-over reference](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html), this can be achieved via maxReconnectDelay, which defaults to 30,000 (milliseconds). However, this doesn't appear to work. For example, using the following still means a 30s delay between trying one broker and trying the next.

```
failover:(tcp://host1:61616,tcp://host2:61616)?maxReconnectDelay=2000
```

Have I misunderstood the configuration, or is this bugged? How do I make the application try the second broker sooner?

Comment: I think you need the ConnectionTimeout property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the ConnectionTimeOut property **per host** like this:

```
failover:(tcp://host1:61616?connectionTimeout=1000,tcp://host2:61616connectionTimeout=1000)
```

This will timeout the connection in one second to each defined host.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go. Is `maxReconnectDelay` just for the delay on fail-over, after the initial connection then?

Comment: @Spycho "The maximum amount of time we ever wait between reconnect attempts (in ms)"